# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jarvis_api'

Tags: python, nlp, pyaudio

I am making a Chatbot with Mic input for that I am Using Jarvis below code is for Mic Input But when I am executing the code I am getting the error:-

import jarvis_api.audio_pb2 as ja

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jarvis_api'.
I have installed JarvisAI and jarvis api (using pip install JarvisAI) and (npm i api-jarvis).

```
import sys
import grpc
import queue
import argparse

import jarvis_api.audio_pb2 as ja
import jarvis_api.jarvis_asr_pb2 as jasr
import jarvis_api.jarvis_asr_pb2_grpc as jasr_srv

import pyaudio

RATE = 44100
CHUNK = int(RATE/10)

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Streaming transcription via jarvis AI Services")
    parser.add_argument("--server",default='localhost:50051',type=str,help="URI to GRPC Services endpoint")
    parser.add_argument("--input-devices",type=int,default=None,help="output device to use")
    parser.add_argument("--list-devices",action='store_true',help="list output device indices")
    return parser.parse_args()

class MicrophoneStream(object):
    def __init__(self,rate,chunk,device=None):
        self._rate = rate
        self._chunk = chunk
        self._device = device

        self._buff = queue.Queue()
        self.closed = True

    def __enter__(self):
        self._audio_interface = pyaudio.pyAudio()
        self._audio_stream = self._audio_interface.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            input_device_index=self._device,
            channels=1,
            rate=self._rate,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self._chunk,
            stream_callback=self._fill_buffer,
        )
        self.closed=False
        return self 

    def __exit__(self,type,value,traceback):
        self.audio_stream.stop_stream()
        self.audio_stream.close()
        self.closed= True
        self._buff.put(None)
        self._audio_interface.terminate()

    def generator(self):
        while not self.closed:
            chunk=self._buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]
            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self._buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break
            yield b''.join(data)                    


def listen_print_loop(responses):
    num_chars_printed = 0
    for response in responses:
        if not response.results:
            continue
        result = response.results[0]
        if not result.alternatives:
            continue

        transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
        overwrite_chars = '' * (num_chars_printed - len(transcript))

        if not result.is_final:
            sys.stdout.write(transcript + overwrite_chars + '\r')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            num_chars_printed = len(transcript)

        else:
            print(transcript + overwrite_chars)
            num_chars_printed = 0

def main():
    args = get_args()
    if args.list_devices:
        p =pyaudio.pyAudio()
        for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
            info = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
            if info['maxInputChannels']<1:
                continue
            print(f"{info['index']}:{info['name']}")
        sys.exit(0)
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel(args.server)
    client = jasr_srv.JarvisASRStub(channel)

    config = jasr.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=ja.AudioEncoding.LINEAR_PCM,
        sample_rate_hertz=RATE,
        language_code="en-US",
        max_alternatives=1,
        enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
    )
    streaming_config = jasr.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config,interim_results=True)

    with MicrophoneStream(RATE,CHUNK,device=args.input_device) as stream:
        audio_generator = stream.generator()
        requests = (jasr.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content) for content in audio_generator)
        def build_generator(cfg,gen):
            yield jasr.StreamingRecognizeRequest(streaming_config=cfg)
            for x in gen:
                yield x
        responses = client.StreamingRecognize(build_generator(streaming_config,requests))
        listen_print_loop(responses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: how are you running your code? from console, from an IDE? Do you have any virtual environment activated?

Comment: I am using Terminal without creating virtual environment should i create?